# Compatible with older versions of Android

Tags: android, backwards-compatibility

http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html

I have implemented this feature, it quite well works on android 4.0 and up.

But I need to make this project compatible with android 2.2, 3.0 etc.

I tried to add android-support library but it does not work, since someone suggested to do so.

How can I achieve my goal?

Answer (score 1):

It should work with adding the support v4 library jar. However, it is recently added and using an older version of this jar will result in errors.

Update your ADK & ADT and start a new Android project. This will create a new project with the latest and greatest support v4 library. Just copy-paste that in your libs/ folder of your own project to replace the old one.